# Creating a text file filled with random integers in Java

Tags: java, file, text, file-io, random

Stupid question, maybe. But I try to fill an empty text file with 512 integers, each on every new line. I was able to randomize and write them into the file, but they create a huge pile of numbers of what I have wished. Can anyone help me correct my code?

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Randomizer {

      public static void main() {
        // The target file
        File out = new File("random.txt");
        FileWriter fw = null;
        int n = 512;
        // Try block: Most stream operations may throw IO exception
        try {
            // Create file writer object
            fw = new FileWriter(out);
            // Wrap the writer with buffered streams
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            int line;
            Random random = new Random();
            while (n > 0) {
                // Randomize an integer and write it to the output file
                line = random.nextInt(1000);
                writer.write(line + "\n");
                n--;
            }
            // Close the stream
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Content of random.txt at the end of the run:
9463765593113665333437829621346187993554694651813319223268147794541131427390 etc.

Comment: What operating system are you on? On Windows, a line break is `\r\n`, not `\n`.

Comment: i would guess the output is correct, are you using notepad to view the file content? Some editors dont read `\n` as newline character, use `\r\n` instead.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using Windows - line endings are different on Unix/Windows/Classic Mac.

Try \r\n for Windows-based systems, or try to open the .txt file in Wordpad instead of Notepad - \n is commonly used on Unix systems and the Notepad application included with Windows is known not to handle them well.

Answer (score 1):

```
            writer.write(line + "\n");
```

Don't use that.

You use a `BufferedWriter` and a `BufferedWriter` has `.newLine()`.

Therefore replace with:

```
writer.write(line);
writer.newLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this line from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) for `BufferedWriter`:

> A `newLine()` method is provided, which uses the platform's own notion of line separator as defined by the system property line.separator. Not all platforms use the newline character (`'\n'`) to terminate lines. Calling this method to terminate each output line is therefore preferred to writing a newline character directly.