# Creating Files with Random Content

Tags: java

is there any way to create ten random files for each different value of the variable N. I want to have five values of N between the space 100,50000. The differnce between the values should be at least 5000. So for each value of N, I want to create 10 different files and write random values to them. For example the file format can be like this:

```
0  2
5 12
8 23
10 53
56 98
...
```

Comment: I don't have any idea so far.

Comment: Write at least pseudo code. Thing is, we don't want to write a whole program for you, especially without knowing what your problem is - do you have problems writing into files? Do you have problems generating random numbers? What did you found using a search engine and why can't you apply it?

Comment: You can check first the documentation of creating files in java and then how to generate random strings. Do not waith for someone do your work.

Answer (score 0):

to write into a file, using commons.io

```
/**
 * Méthode permettant de créer un nouveau fichier ou d'écraser un fichier
 * existant, tout en lui insérant un contenu.
 *
 * @param strContenu
 *            Chaine à insérer dans le fichier texte
 * @param strPathFichier
 *            Chemin du fichier à créer
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static String creerFichierPlusContenu(   final String strContenu,
                                                final String strPathFichier)
                                                        throws IOException {
    if (strContenu == null || strPathFichier == null) {
        return null;
    }
    File parentFile = new File(strPathFichier).getParentFile();
    if (!parentFile.exists() && !parentFile.mkdirs()) {
        return null;
    }
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(strPathFichier);
    IOUtils.write(strContenu, fileOut, "UTF-8");
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(fileOut);
    return strPathFichier;

}
```

To generate random numbers :

Math.random()

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Code Used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284921/creating-a-text-file-filled-with-random-integers-in-java
 * Modified by: Ilya Kuznetsov (12/15/2016)
 */
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class FillFiles {
    public static void main() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            File file = new File("random" + i + ".txt");
            FileWriter writesToFile = null;
            try {
                // Create file writer object
                writesToFile = new FileWriter(file);
                // Wrap the writer with buffered streams
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(writesToFile);
                int line;
                Random rand = new Random();
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                    // Randomize an integer and write it to the output file
                    line = rand.nextInt(50000);
                    writer.write(line + "\n");
                }
                // Close the stream
                writer.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should work, any questions or comments, feel free to ask.